# displaying revenue for each year

Tags: mysql, sql, northwind

I'm using NorthWind SQL database. For those who are not familiar, it has some of the following tables:

```
 Orders, 
 OrderDetails, 
 Products,  
 categories 
 (Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID) 
 (Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID)
 (Categories.categoryID = Products.categoryID)
 
 Orders has a column named "OrderDate" (formatted as dd/mm/yy)
 OrderDetails has a column named "Price"
```

I need to display the total "revenue" for each year. That is, the sum of all "prices". Any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, as we don't have your complete table structure. This way of GROUP BY is for MySQL

```
   SELECT SUM (OD.Price) AS Revenue FROM OrderDetails OD
    INNER JOIN Orders O ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
    GROUP BY YEAR(O.OrderDate);
```